# Angular trying to use ngModel on html element

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel, ngmodel

What Im trying is this:

```
    <div class = "form-group">
  <label for="funktion">Funktion</label>
  <select formControlName="funktion" id="funktion" class="form-control" ngModel #Funktion="ngModel" required >
    <option *ngFor="let Funktion of funktionen" value="{{Funktion.Name}}">{{Funktion.Name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div *ngIf="Funktion.value == 'Administrator' ">
  Some Text here
</div>
```

But it get the following error:

There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("      ]#Funktion="ngModel" required >

My Goal is to show the  if the Funktion with the value "Administrator" is slected on the dropdown and hide it if "Administrator" is not selected...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add the .ts file code for this component too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <div class = "form-group">
      <label for="funktion">Funktion</label>
      <select formControlName="funktion" id="funktion" [(ngModel)]="Funktionname" class="form-control"  required >
       <option *ngFor="let Funktion of funktionen" value="{{Funktion.Name}}">{{Funktion.Name}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="Funktionname == 'Administrator' ">
    Some Text here
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you this is working! Could u explain that to me?

Comment: Sure @Kai, Funktionname is a model , when you change any item from the it'll hold Funktionname model hold the changed value. glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class = "form-group">
  <label for="funktion">Funktion</label>
  <select class="form-control" formControlName="funktion" id="funktion"  [(ngModel)]='seletedValue' required >
    <option *ngFor="let Funktion of dataList" value="{{Funktion.value}}">{{Funktion.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div *ngIf="seletedValue == 'Administrator' ">
  Some Text here
</div>
```

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dy2ocv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I resolved it using

```
 <div class = "form-group">
    <label for="funktion">Funktion</label>
    <select formControlName="funktion" id="funktion" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="myFuncName" #Funktion="ngModel" required >
       <option *ngFor="let Funktion of funktionen" value="{{Funktion.Name}}">{{Funktion.Name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div *ngIf="myFuncName == 'Administrator' ">
   Some Text here
</div>
```